# Move tabs to the side of Safari

Tags: safari, software-recommendation, web-browser, web-browsing

Some employees in my office get confused by tabs on the top of Safari. It is  measurably affecting productivity.

- I need to get the tabs on the left side of the screen with a title next to each tab.
- We currently use Safari because it has adblock ("Ka-Block!"). We cannot deploy any solution in this company if it results in my employees seeing ads.
- Pinning tabs makes the favorite icon far too small for usability (we tried)
- Our main use case is webmail with two accounts. When there is not a very large indication one account isn’t open - new tabs arrive complicating the work flow.
- the requirement is to have large names and visual space to identify each open tab in Safari.

I will pay money for this solution.

What options are available?

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you use Safari for Ka-Block but if you could find an alternative blocker for Firefox you could get the side tab you want.  There's an extension call Tree Style Tab which lets you put them on the right or left side of the screen.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/